# Building a 2D Polar Histogram with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

When I read the paper [*G.A.* Jacobs *et al*./ *Advances in Space Research*, **68** (2021), 746--761](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0273117719306660), I found such an interesting figure:

[image]

Let's call it a 2D polar histogram. (Maybe it has a more suitable name?)

My question is: **can I plot this kind of 2D polar histogram with PGFPlots?**

---

I'm trying to find other ways to draw. I found a scheme for plotting using python, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63887605/8097964). Unfortunately, it is a bit buggy.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Unfortunately I don't think that this currently is possible in PGFPlots ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow: I do not know when polar plots was added to PGFPlots, but this site has questions about it back from 2011.

Answer (score 4):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

There is a for loop which loops over the slices. Here, each slice has 3 numbers which denote the angle, the radius and the value.

Each slice is drawn by a separate `\wheelchart`.

The radius is interpreted with the function `\WCdefradius`. The value determines the color. The angle determines the start angle of the slice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\readlist\WCcolors{MidnightBlue,Cyan,Green,Yellow,Orange,Red}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\def\a{30}
\def\r{10}
\def\WCdefradius#1{\fpeval{trunc(#1/\r,0)*\r}}
\foreach\angle/\radius/\value in {
  4/2.9/180,2/11/90,21/25/48,1/31/7,25/53/0,
  34/2.9/43,32/11/90,51/25/9,31/31/11,59/49/4,
  64/2.9/91,62/11/36,81/25/81,89/49/7,85/53/3,
  94/2.9/180,92/11/90,91/31/7,119/49/4,115/53/0,
  124/2.9/123,122/11/90,141/25/9,121/31/11,
  154/2.9/92,152/11/203,171/25/81,151/31/7,
  184/2.9/180,182/11/90,201/25/48,181/31/7,205/53/0,
  214/2.9/43,212/11/90,231/25/9,211/31/11,239/49/4,
  244/2.9/91,242/11/36,261/25/81,269/49/4,265/53/0,
  274/2.9/180,272/11/90,271/31/7,299/49/4,295/53/0,
  304/2.9/123,302/11/90,301/25/108,301/31/11,
  334/2.9/92,332/11/36,351/25/81,331/31/7
}{
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  radius={\WCdefradius{\radius}}{\WCdefradius{\radius}+\r},
  slices style={
    /utils/exec={
      \pgfmathparse{
        \value<1?1:
        (\value<5?2:
        (\value<10?3:
        (\value<50?4:
        (\value<100?5:
        6
        ))))
      }
    },
    \WCcolors[\pgfmathresult]
  },
  start angle={int(\angle/\a)*\a},
  total angle=\a,
  value=1
]{\angle/\radius/\value}
}
\draw (0,0) circle[radius={6*\r}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice result! congratulations

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
xmin=0, xmax=360,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
xtick distance=45,
axis on top,
colormap/jet,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
domain=0:360, samples=37,
domain y=0:1, samples y=40,
x filter/.expression={rnd^2*y>0.5?nan:x},
unbounded coords=jump,
] {-y*(sin(3*x)+rnd)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Polar color circle with missing patches]

*Edit:* With `surf, shader=flat,` and an other test function:

[image: Polar color circle with missing patches]